# Adding list of items using TextFormField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, controller, textformfield

I am trying to implement the feature to add a list of emails input but the user. This is what i have so far

```
  List<String> _notificationEmails =[];
  var _notificationEmailsController = TextEditingController();
  Widget _buildNotificationEmailsInput() {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: _notificationEmailsController,
      style: inputTextStyle,
      maxLines: null,
      validator: (String value) {
        print(value);
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Emails Required';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onChanged: (String value){
        if(value.substring(value.length-1)==','){
          print('here');
            setState(() {
              _notificationEmails.add(value.substring(0,value.length-1));
            });
          _notificationEmailsController.clear();
        }
        print(_notificationEmails);
      },
    );
  }
```

My intended outcome is that when the user enters an email then adds a comma after it, the email is appended o the list and the input field cleared but i get a loop of the action resulting to this `_notificationEmails.add(value.substring(0,value.length-1));`  running to infinity.

**Here are the logs**

```
[   +3 ms] flutter: [je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gmail.com, je@gm<…>
```

This goes on and on. What have I done wrong?

**Update**

Incase it helps, i have realised the issue is brought about because every time the `_notificationEmailsController.clear();` is called, it triggers `onChange()` thus the loop.

Comment: Try to call ```clear``` before ```setState```. I think the onChange is called due to setState.

Comment: @danypata The problem still persists.

Comment: You got to do 2 things here. First check if the email is a valid you can use regex to check that and Second check if the email is already existing in the list and then proceed to add it

Comment: @DannyRufus Validation is not my issue

Comment: @Bright Okay from what I understand, the issue you are facing is after you write a comma the string value is adding to the list infinitely? correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The comma is actually ment to be there in that it separates multiple emails into the list.

Comment: Your problem is from a different place i think. I've tested your code on FlutLab.io and it works for me. Is the ```here``` message printed multiple times ?

Comment: @Bright I updated my answer to only use same instance of `TextEditingController`.

Comment: @danypata I think it works well because you are using flutlab.io. In response to rickimaru's answer, the delay solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Please call `TextEditingController.clear` inside a `Future.delayed`. Because based from the description of `clear`...

> this method should only be called between frames, e.g. in response to
> user actions, not during the build, layout, or paint phases.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyApp createState() => _MyApp();
}

class _MyApp extends State<MyApp> {
  final List<String> _notificationEmails = <String>[];
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            _buildNotificationEmailsInput(),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _notificationEmails.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, int idx) => ListTile(
                  title: Text(_notificationEmails[idx]),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildNotificationEmailsInput() {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: _controller,
      validator: (String value) {
        print('VALIDATOR: $value');
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Emails Required';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onChanged: (String value) {
        if (value.substring(value.length - 1) == ',') {
          print('>>>>>> value = $value : controller = ${_controller.hashCode}');
          setState(() {
            _notificationEmails.add(value.substring(0, value.length - 1));
          });
          Future<void>.delayed(
            const Duration(milliseconds: 10),
            _controller.clear,
          );
          print(_notificationEmails);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
**You have to add a list of *TextEditingController* and need to add the contoller text to that list and parse it as you need.**     
     
      List<String> selection = [];  
     List<Product> productList = []; 

     //---------Adding contoller to list   
      
     productProvider.getAll(user.guid).forEach((element) {//---List<Product>
     final TextEditingController quantityController = 
     TextEditingController(text: element.quantity);
     quantityControllers.add(quantityController);
     });

       //-------Adding list of products to list
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> productItems = [];
       List<Product> productOriginalList = 
       productProvider.getAll(user.guid);
       for (int i = 0; i < productOriginalList.length; i++) {
       final Product product = productOriginalList[i];
       if (selection.contains(product.equipmentId)) {
                   
       productItems.add(product.toJson(quantityControllers[i].text));
                  }

     /* Map<String, dynamic> toJson(String quan) => {
    'ProductId': id,
    'Quantity': quan,
     };     
    TextField(
    controller: quantityControllers[index],*/
```